# How can I test the hashtag search API without app reviews?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to use the Instagram API to create an application that displays hashtag search results.

I'd like to test for that, but I'm asked for an app review to do a hashtag search.

Do I need an app review when I can't test the functionality?

Please let me know if there is a way to test without app reviews. I am in great trouble.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to test the API:

Create a Facebook developper account and try out Facebook graph explorer.

If you want to actually test the API in your app:

If you want to get data from Facebook in your app, you will have to create a Facebook app on Facebook developers platform. You will most likely have to implement Facebook login in your app, and add permissions in your code. You are free to use any permissions within your app. If you want to go live, you will have to request advanced access.

But keep in mind that the hashtag search endpoint only gives little information, I suggest you check the documentation to check if this lets you get the information you need.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/instagram-public-content-access/

Comment: Thank you for answering this question.
After all, I get only limited information in the tests.
I'm considering a review of the app. thank you very much!